# Should I use "reminiscences" or "reminiscing" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> “Excuse me,” said a voice, dragging Mary out of her sour **reminiscing/reminiscing**.

What's the correct word and why?

Comment: you've written the same word twice fyi. Based on the title of the post, I would choose 'reminiscing', but reminiscences would also work. It also depends a bit on whether the action of reminiscing is sour (perhaps the memories are not, perhaps they are good), or whether the reminiscences are themselves sour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Reminiscence* is a noun that means "a story told about a past event remembered by the narrator" according to Google.

*Reminiscing* would be the gerund form of *reminisce* - and it would refer to an action or activity in progress.

Unless Mary was telling stories, *reminiscing* is likely what you want.

Comment: -1.  Google gives the most salient or common meanings. It's not to be relied on as you have done here. Collins, for example, gives "the act of recalling or narrating past experiences"